# Why are all of my line-breaks changing from "/r/n" to "/n/" and how can I stop this from happening?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq-to-xml

I am saving my files as xml documents, using XDocument.Save(path), and after saving and loading a document all of the line breaks have changed from "/r/n" to "/n/". Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `XmlWriterSettings` to control what your line-break characters are:

```
XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
xws.NewLineChars = "\r\n";
using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create("whatever.xml", xws))
{
   xmlDocumentInstance.Save(xw);
}
```

Whatever you're using to read in your XML might be normalizing your line endings.

Comment: It is still not working. I am using XDocument.Load(path) to load the file.

Comment: Do you need line breaks at all? Could you just save and load the XML while completely ignoring whitespace? Maybe we're trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: I do need the line breaks. The xml file that I am working with is a custom filetype for the text editor that I'm working on.

I was able to solve my problem by using these settings:

`xws.NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine;
xws.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace;`

However, I still don't understand what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the PreserveWhiteSpace property on your XmlDocument object before calling Load() and Save() then this will not happen:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
doc.Load("foo.xml");
...
doc.Save("bar.xml"); // Line endings will not be altered
```